# Margin: 0 auto leaves page aligned slightly right?

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

So I've got a header / main body / footer centred with margin: 0 auto, and width 1024px - but on a mobile / ipad it seems to be pushed slightly right, leaving a white margin on the left.

http://tailoredadvantage.org/default.html

Is there a simple fix to this? Maybe a min-width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific. What ipad ie what resolution? A quick look at your code and your page isn't responsive, so being LTR its always going to look like that if the page is bigger than the actual screen size its displayed on.

By using;

```
@media all and (max-width:1024px) {

    html, body {
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

You remove that margin when the screensize is lower than the page width (of 1020px).

Comment: Appreciate the response - I'm new to the game. Page isn't responsive yet. Only issue with padding: 0; is that when viewed on a larger screen - say a laptop - it fixes the page to the left? Just looking for some code that would allow a page to be centred on screens above 1020px and fill a mobile / ipad screen

Comment: Just use the updated code, any screen under 1024px will have no margin applied.

Comment: No worries! If that fixed the problem please select my post as the answer :)